# Push Notification completion handler in background

Tags: objective-c

I have implemented the following method to get push notification on iOS 7. Here are some settings that I did for iOS 7.
 
1. Added content-available: 1 in push payload.
 
2. Added the remote-notification background mode in Info.plist and checked remote-notification in project settings under capabilities.
 
3. Written following method in app delegate.

```
-(void) application: (UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void(^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    //sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"A URL THAT RETURNS JSON"]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                // handle response
                NSLog(@"Response Received %@",data);
                // Parse JSON Data Here.
            }] resume];
    // I tried data download with NSURLConnection and NSURLSession both individually.
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Now on getting push, the above delegate is called and all statements get executed, but the called URL does not get data in background, but as soon as the app is launched within 30 seconds, data is downloaded from server. But if app is launched post 30 second then server timeout occurs. Can you please let me know if it's possible to handle received data while the app is in the background?

Comment: what you do till...show here and show some code

Answer (score 0):

If your application is in BackGround at that time you can call the Url in AppDelegate Class.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if([launchOptions valueForKeyPath:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] !=NULL){
//App Launched by PushNotification,Here you can call URL
}
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{

}
```

Comment: if it's possible to handle received data while the app is in the background and not suspended? Because while transition from background didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will not be called.